# How can I make a part of the form partially transparent in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

I want to make a part of a form semi-transparent, with additional text on that part which is not transparent.

How can I accomplish this in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can apply transparency (more correctly termed, *Opacity*) to only a part of a form rather than the complete, whole form.

You can, however, create a custom shaped form (i.e. non-rectangular) quite easily, with various parts of that form being transparent.  Depending upon the exact "look" that you're trying to achieve, this may be closest you'll get.

Take a look at these links for creating your own custom-shaped form:

[Creating Custom Shaped Windows Forms in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/customforms.aspx)
[Custom shaped form with a drop down in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/customcsforms.aspx)
[Shaped Windows Forms and Controls in Visual Studio .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289517%28VS.71%29.aspx)

The only other alternative may be to display two forms, one of which is set to be partially transparent.  You would have to programmatically ensure that the second form is positioned immediately next to the "main" form, and is moved/resized proportionately when the user moves/resizes the "main" form.  Although this is two forms, it could be made to look, to the user, that it's actually only one form, although this could be quite tricky to pull off, and would not be a perfect solution (but may be "good enough" depending upon your exact needs).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by creating a fully-transparent window in your form, and then floating a semi-transparent form over the fully-transparent window.

First, set the TransparencyKey of your main form to Color.Red, then place a Panel named `panel1` on the form, and set its BackColor to Red.  This will create the fully-transparent "window".  Create a form-level Form reference like this:

```
private Form _floater;
```

Next, put this code in your main form's Load event:

```
_floater = new Form();
_floater.ShowInTaskbar = false;
_floater.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
_floater.Opacity = .5;
_floater.Size = panel1.Size;
_floater.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
_floater.Location = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
_floater.Show(this);
```

Finally, put this code in your main form's Move event:

```
_floater.Location = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
```

The only issue here is that if the user clicks in the semi-transparent "window", the second form will get the focus, so your main form's TitleBar is grayed out.

[Click here](http://www.musigenesis.com/SO/sample.exe) to run a sample application with this semi-transparent window on a form.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if this is even possible with WinForms without exzessessive use of p/invoke calls and workarounds.

You may want to use Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) instead, where such effects are almost trivial to implement.

Comment: Why -1? What was wrong with my answer? In WinForms you can set transparency only on the complete form but not on parts on it, so I doubt it can be done easily.

Comment: +1 to counteract the downvote. It's not that hard to do this in WinForms, but it *is* slightly hacky and WPF *is* better for this kind of thing (although it's less fun when the MS engineers do everything for you).

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
myForm.Opacity = 80; // Change 80 with your value
```

Comment: @FBSC - That'll change the opacity of the complete form.  It sounds like the original question asker only wants to change the opacity of a part of the form, not the whole form.

Comment: Sorry, i skipped that "part" :S