# exclude a part of an image by taking color

Tags: c#, winforms, image

My problem is quite simple, but I can't deal with it. I have a yin-yang.jpg file and I'd like to get only round shape (without rest of rectangle, which should be not clickable) and what is more whole white color change to red one and parts with black color should be excluded from an image as well (not clickable).

That image will be background of my form, which I'd like to show at the start of an application.

```
private void hello_form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Form f = (Form)sender;
        f.BackgroundImage = global::TicTacToe.Properties.Resources.ying_yang1;
        GraphicsPath formPath = new GraphicsPath();
        Rectangle newRectangle = f.ClientRectangle;
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, newRectangle);
        newRectangle.Inflate(-5, -5);
        formPath.AddEllipse(newRectangle);
        f.Region = new Region(formPath);

    }
```

Paint event on my form which I show makes them round, but it's not all things I have to do. How to exclude a black part from a background and how to change white part into red one?

Comment: Can you provide more in-depth information about what it is you're trying to achieve in a better formatted way please? Precisely what is it you're attempting to achieve?

Comment: My application is one form shows at the centerscreen. 
-form is a square
-background of form is a yin-yang.jpg
-only round of yin-yang is visible, rest of form is transparent (I can click through the this rest of rectangle)
-yin-yang is made by two colors by default: white and black
-I'd like to change them dynamically: white color change into red one, and black color exclude from form (I can click through this part too)

Effect like this:
http://i45.tinypic.com/2hofse1.jpg

Or maybe is a better way to show this than show as form?

Comment: It's my yin-yang file
http://mor.phe.us/writings/Yin-Yang.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you've described you may find:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.maketransparent(v=vs.71).aspx

`Bitmap.MakeTransparent()` a useful method to explore, it allows you to turn a given colour in your image transparent.

Comment: It makes my color transparent, but beneath my background Image is a form that cannot be transparent, so I have to exclude a region with black color completely from form (including form).
And it's not "nice" way, how to make it more smoothier ?

Maybe I'd rather select white parts and then use a Region.Exclude function. But how do this?

Comment: @user2248836 Wait, are you trying to say you want the black section on the form to "cut" through the form to reveal what's underneath the form? Effectively turning that part of the form transparent?

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm sorry for my inaccuracy.

Comment: @user2248836 then if your form cannot be transparent then there is no way of achieving this that I'm aware of, you can set your forms transparency key to be a colour then set the background image region you want excluded to that colour, that way that region will go straight through the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a file with transparent background like a .png or .gif you should be able to only see the round yin-yang shape when you set it as form background. 
You can easily edit a .jpg with i.e. GIMP or Photoshop to make the rectangle transparent outside the circle.

edit: is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: But I have only not-transparent image and I have to change it dynamically in my code.

Comment: reading your comments on the other answer, I have looked for something which might be useful. Have you read this topic yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550371/how-can-i-make-a-part-of-the-form-partially-transparent-in-c